# VMSS - Backend pool unassociated by default for LoadBalancer

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

We have a kubernetes cluster which we deploy using aks-engine and we recently moved from VM to VMSS as nodes. But, when we deploy a service using helm, the backend pools of the load balancer that gets created doesn't get associated to the Virtual Machine Scale Set that's created as part of the deployment. We expect it to be associated to it by default. Right now, we need to manually perform this step. Can we have a way to automatically do this ?

Here's the kubernetes.json file

```
    {  
   "apiVersion":"vlabs",
   "properties":{  
      "orchestratorProfile":{  
         "orchestratorType":"Kubernetes",
         "orchestratorRelease":"1.12",
         "kubernetesConfig":{  
            "networkPolicy":"azure",
            "useManagedIdentity":true
         }
      },
      "masterProfile":{  
         "count":1,
         "dnsPrefix":"testcluster",
         "vmSize":"Standard_D2_v2"
      },
      "agentPoolProfiles":[  
         {  
            "name":"windowspool2",
            "count":2,
            "vmSize":"Standard_D2_v2",
            "availabilityProfile":"VirtualMachineScaleSets",
            "osType":"Windows",
            "osDiskSizeGB":127
         }
      ],
      "windowsProfile":{  
         "adminUsername":"azureuser",
         "adminPassword":"test1234",
         "windowsPublisher":"MicrosoftWindowsServer",
         "windowsOffer":"WindowsServerSemiAnnual",
         "windowsSku":"Datacenter-Core-1803-with-Containers-smalldisk"
      },
      "linuxProfile":{  
         "adminUsername":"azureuser",
         "ssh":{  
            "publicKeys":[  
               {  
                  "keyData":<ssh-key>
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "servicePrincipalProfile":{  
         "clientId":         <SP-client ID> ,
         "secret":<SP-client passowrd>
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: does this not happen when you deploy service manually?

Comment: Can you show the deployment file of your kubernetes? Need for more details of your kubernetes settings.

Comment: Thanks your response. I've updated my post with the kubernetes deployment file.

Yes, it happens when I deploy the service through helm

Comment: It seems that you create the windows nodes, so you do not need to set the `linuxProfile`. Actually, you just manage the cluster through the master node and access the application through the load balancer, so you do not need to expose the client node to the public, why do you want to do this?